# Configure modal with Materialize framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

Im using [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/) framework on my project and I need to configure their modal to, for example, do not close when I click outside the modal window. I also need to trigger the modal from my js code.

According with their [documentation](http://materializecss.com/modals.html) this code below should do the work:

```
$('.modal').modal({dismissible: false});
```

This is the code that I use to trigger the modal:

```
$('#modal1').modal('open');
```

This modal is being triggered but the `dismissible` isn't working.
What is going on right here??

You should know what else i've tried:

```
$('#modal1').modal({dismissible: false}); // fair enough...
$('#modal1').modal('open', {dismissible: false}); // why not?
$("#modal1").openModal({dismissible: false}); // This works on older versions (https://codepen.io/Dogfalo/pen/qdrBev)
$("#modal1").leanModal({dismissible: false}); // Another old command but it doesn't work even there.
```

I have no idea what is happening. I need some help.

Comment: I had to talk with some people at Materialize's community and apparently it was a bug at 0.99.0 version. Already fixed since they're at 0.100.2 by now, and it's working on this newest version. Here's the link: https://codepen.io/theakira/pen/gGGbxg